# CSS Horizontal sub menu - IE 6,7 both dont working, tried with whatever hover

Tags: css, menu, hover, submenu

I'm not expert about css menus. But I know basic system to make css menu.
I used this system before and works, but this time it is not working.

The site is http://www.uniethos.com. Please check this site

This menu works with all other latest Browsers. But not with IE 6 & 7. I know IE6 don't support hover except anchor. So before I was using Whatever Hover. But this time it is not working and even with IE7. I don't know why its happening. May be there could be some problem with my css. Please check the css.

If you don't have IE 6 or 7 installed you can run one from http://spoon.net/browsers/. Require to install one plugin.

The CSS I'm using for the menu is

```
.glossymenu{
    background: #B4B3B3;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

}

.glossymenu ul
{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0; 
   padding-left: 0px;
}

.glossymenu li ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 80%;
    top:30px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:#5B0C10;
    border:0px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.glossymenu li li a
{
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; 
}    

.glossymenu li li a:hover
{
    background : #871016; 

}

.glossymenu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
}

.glossymenu li a{
    float: left;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:0 0 0 16px; /*Padding to accomodate left tab image. Do not change*/
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.glossymenu li a b{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 24px 0 8px; /*Padding of menu items*/
}

.glossymenu li.current a, .glossymenu li a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    background: #5B0C10;
    background-position: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glossymenu li a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glossymenu ul li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't found the problem. But I fixed the menu with custom Javascript code.

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("glossymenu").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" over";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" over\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
```

People those are also facing the same problem may find this helpfull.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse whatever:hover is best. But I don't know why that was not working.
If you face the same problem, you can use this javascript. But you have to understand the code.

```
sfHover = function() { 
// You may have to change the "glossymenu" id with your one
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("glossymenu").getElementsByTagName("LI"); 


    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) { 
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() { 
            this.className+=" over"; 
        } 
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() { 
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" over\\b"), ""); 
        } 
    }  }  if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
```

In my case, I have a div id named "glossymenu". You have to change this with your id.
And also have to declare another CSS class named "over".
In my case -

```
.glossymenu li:hover ul, .glossymenu li.over ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

This is enough for one level dropdown menu. You don't need whatever:hover if its ok with you.